# Select all rows where two columns contain a combination of values

Tags: sql

Here's my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE T (A CHAR(1), B CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO T (A, B) VALUES('1', '1');
INSERT INTO T (A, B) VALUES('2', '2');
INSERT INTO T (A, B) VALUES('1', '2');
```

I wan't to select rows where columns A and B contain a combination of values. For example, lets say I want to find combinations A=1,B=1, and A=2,B=2, and nothing else. If it were a single value, I could use the IN statement, but when I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE A IN ('1', '2') AND B IN ('1', '2')
```

I get back all three rows.

How can I match a combination of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this query :

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE (A,B) IN (('1', '1'),('2', '2'));
```

see given link below

Click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc2535/11)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for using `OR` with parentheses?

```
select * 
from T
where ( A = '1' AND B = '1' ) OR ( A = '2' AND B = '2' )
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc2535/1)

Comment: Is there a way to do it with an IN statement so I can avoid building all the sql?

Comment: @ConditionRacer -- I would recommend using `or`, but there are other alternatives such as `where concat(a,b) in ('11','22')` -- `concat` is mysql, but other rdbms have similar approaches...

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like below sql

SELECT * FROM T WHERE (A == B) AND A IN ('1', '2');