# SQL Hive: select (*) LIMIT 1 based on a combination of 3 columns, union in R, RODBC

Tags: r, hive, impala

I'm an intern working with big data and this is my first question. If I'm not asking it well, please let me know how to improve.

I have a very large table that I'm querying through Hive via R's RODBC package.

Let's say that table has columns named `A:ZZZ`.

I'd like to pull one row, with all columns, for every unique combination of 3 columns, let's say **B**, **F**, and **G**.

I ran the below query to get all unique combinations of B, F and G and came up with a little over 7000:

```
select B, F, G, count(*)
from DB.tableName
group by B, F, G;
```

I did a lot of research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430641/select-all-rows-where-two-columns-contain-a-combination-of-values):

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE (A,B) IN (('1', '1'),('2', '2'));
```

I currently have all my combinations of **B**, **F** and **G** stored as a data frame in R. I thought that if I could convert the data frame of combinations into a vector that I named `TestVector`, that I could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM DB.Table WHERE (B,F,G) IN TestVector LIMIT 1;
```

but I get these errors, and don't know how to fix the syntax:

```
[1] "HY000 110 [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 5:\n              (B, F, G)\n                    ^\nEncountered: COMMA\nExpected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, IN, IS, LIKE, NOT, OR, REGEXP, RLIKE\n\nCAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error\n"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select *\n              from \n              DB.table \n              WHERE \n              (B, F, G)\n              IN (vectorTest)\n              LIMIT 1;'"
```

Please help!

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to pull one row, with all columns, for every unique
>   combination of 3 columns, let's say B, F, and G.

Queries like this are typically solved using `row_number` to enumerate each row in a group and select rows with a certain row number.

```
select * from (
  select * , 
    row_number() over (partition by B, F, G order by id) rn
  from DB.tableName
) t where rn = 1
```

The query above will pick the row with the lowest `id` for each `B,F,G` group.